# how to remove class if array list is empty inside jsp page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

i have following code i want to remove `tbl-content` class if `recordList` array is empty

```
<table id="gradient-style">
 <tbody class="tbl-content">
  <tr>
         <%
            for (RecordBean record : recordList) {
           // some code here to get result      
         }              
        %>
        <%
            if (recordList.isEmpty()) 
          {
        %>            
            <tr>
               <td colspan="12" align="center" style="color: red;font-family: verdana"> 
                  <h3>No Search records </h3>
              </td>
           </tr>
            <%      
               }
            %>
       </tbody>
   </table>
```

here is css

```
 .tbl-content{   
     height: 650px;;
     overflow: auto;
     position: absolute;
     border: 1px solid gray;
     border-top: none;  
     }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this server side inline code

```
<tbody class="<%= recordList.isEmpty()?"":"tbl-content" %>">
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write JSTL code directly in script tag.

```
 <script>    
<c:if test="${empty recordList}">
//write code here to remove class
</c:if>
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Java Expression Language. Its not good practice to use Java Scriptlet. Also you want to be careful not to use JSTL with JavaScript its a mix of concern.

```
<tbody class=" ${empty recordList ? '' : 'tbl-content' }" >
```

Answer (score 1):

do it this way:

```
<table id="gradient-style">
 <tbody
<%
            if (!recordList.isEmpty()) 
          {
        %> 
class="tbl-content"
 <%      
               }
            %>
>
  <tr>
         <%
            for (RecordBean record : recordList) {
           // some code here to get result      
         }              
        %>
        <%
            if (recordList.isEmpty()) 
          {
        %>            
            <tr>
               <td colspan="12" align="center" style="color: red;font-family: verdana"> 
                  <h3>No Search records </h3>
              </td>
           </tr>
            <%      
               }
            %>
       </tbody>
   </table>
```